# Rails 4 - method to check if all attributes are true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I'm trying to make an app in rails 4.

I want to write a method in a model to check if all attributes are true.

I'm trying:

```
def ready_to_go
    if 
    [ payment == true, 
    && terms == true
    && identification == true
    && key_org == true
    && key_business == true
    && docs == true
    && funding == true
    && contract == true
    && governance == true
    && internal == true
    && preferences == true
    && address == true
    && interest == true ]
    end
  end
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with this?

Comment: Define wrong, do you mean can it be more concise?  or that it's not working?  I don't understand why you have the array syntax `[` and `]` or why it's in an `if` with nothing in it.  If you want to just return true or false then remove both the if and the array syntax

Comment: instead of it try like this in model `self.attributes` to get all attributes of that model.

Answer (score 3):

The `[...]` is wrong. It defines an array. An arry with one element 'false' is interpreted as true.  Just remove the brackets (or use round brackets if you really need them to not get confused).

And start your `if` at the same line.
If you just want to return true/false, you can remove the `if` altogether.
And if your values are `true` or either `false` or `nil`, you also don't need to check against true:

```
def ready_to_go
  payment &&
  terms &&
  identification &&
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to define method and check whether it is ready to go or not, then:

```
def ready_to_go
  [ payment, terms, identification, key_org, key_business, docs, funding, contract, governance, internal, preferences, address, interest].all?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `Array.all?`

```
[true, false].all? # false  
[true, true].all? # true
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use `?` sign to define method as predicate. Then remove comparison with true and just use `payment && terms && ...`

```
def ready_to_go?
  payment &&
  terms &&
  ...
end
```